# Can I integrate $\frac{x}{1-x}$ by substitution?

Tags: integration

I saw a person use substitution like this:

$$\int \frac{x}{1-x} dx$$

Let $u= (1-x)$, $x= 1-u, du= -1\cdot dx$ $\Rightarrow$ $-du=dx$

$$\int \frac{1-u}u (-du)$$

Can I use substitution like this? I never seen it used this way before. Is my math correct for integrating $\frac{x}{1-x}$?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Yes, that's fine.

Comment: Yes until your integration limits doesn't include 1

Comment: Sure you can. Or without substitution: $\frac{x}{1-x}=\frac{(x-1)+1}{1-x}=-1-\frac{1}{x-1}$ and now integrate.

Answer (score 1):

*What you have done is fine.*

*You can also do the same thing using [integration by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts)*

$$\begin{align}\int \dfrac{x}{1-x}dx&=x\int \dfrac{dx}{1-x}+\int \ln (1-x)dx\\ &=-x\ln(1-x)+(x-1)\ln(1-x)-x+c\\&=-\ln(1-x)-x+c \end{align}$$ $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 0):

Of course that's correct. The reason for doing that is because then you get a integral which can easily be integrated using the power rule (or the natural logarithm): $\int x^n dx = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} + c$ or $\int x^{-1} dx = \ln |x| +c$. Also when you perform the substitution you need the entire integrand in terms of $u$ so you may manipulate the substitution expression however way you want to in order to get the integrand in terms of $u$ completely.

Note then $\frac{1-u}{u} = \frac{1}{u} - 1= u^{-1} -1$ which is much more manageable as compared to the original integrand.